# Lockscreen widget needs 2 clicks on any view to have the desired action

Tags: android, android-appwidget, lockscreen

I am using Android 4.2 for adding widget on Lock screen. I am facing two issues:

1. Lock screen widget needs 2 clicks on any view to have the desired action. I mean the user has to click two times on any of the buttons (for example) to perform desired action.
2. Lock screen widget looses the string displayed on some of the views when screen is turned off and on.

Home screen widget (the same widget) is working fine. The issues are observed only with lock screen widget.

Thanks in advance,

Nemat

Comment: Maybe you should post a part of your code here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help you but it's worth mentioning. I thought I had exactly this problem with a lock screen list view widget. It seemed I had to click items 2 or 3 times for it to launch my intent. I discovered that the actual problem was that I was only setting the intent for one of the elements within my listview item.

Just make sure that you are setting the fill in intent for the whole listview item and not one of the views within it.

```
remoteview.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.listview_item, fillInIntent);
```

Example Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<TextView .....
/>

<TextView .....
/>

<ImageView .....
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```